# Query to cassandra object mapper

Tags: python, cassandra, orm

Im trying to figure out how to replace these two query's with Object Mapper, since that is a requirement, but I cannot resolve this.

Anyone that can point me to the right direction?

Query's is pasted below

I've tried with filter() but it will not work

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT gocd, serverdependencies, jenkins, nodes FROM application WHERE name=%s',{apps})

rows = session.execute('SELECT toJson(address) FROM service WHERE servicename=%s', [service])
    for row in rows:
        result.append(row)
```

Comment: what is your schema?

Comment: test.application (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    gocd list<text>,
    jenkins list<text>,
    nodes list<text>,
    serverdependencies list<text>

Comment: test.service (
    servicename text PRIMARY KEY,
    address text,
    matchtype list<text>,
    samplingtype list<text>,
    servicetype list<text>

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.17/object_mapper/).  I just checked with latest version of driver, and `filter` works just fine:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection

class Application(Model):
     name = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
     gocd = columns.List(value_type=columns.Text)
     jenkins = columns.List(value_type=columns.Text)
     serverdependencies = columns.List(value_type=columns.Text)

connection.setup(['127.0.0.1'], "test", protocol_version=3)
q = Application.objects.filter(name='test')
q[:]
```

and it outputs following:

```
[Application(name='test', gocd=[u'test'], jenkins=[], serverdependencies=[])]
```

for following data:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT * from application ;

 name | gocd     | jenkins | nodes | serverdependencies
------+----------+---------+-------+--------------------
 test | ['test'] |    null |  null |               null
```